# AWS Chime Audio Calling option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

Does AWS Chime Provide a Separate Audio Calling option?
And does Chime supports the below Options,

1. Audio Call
2. Video Call
3. Screen share
4. Phone Call
5. SMS
6. Recordings
7. Merging
8. Storage options
9. Group calling

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

you can find most of them in link below
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-sdk/tree/main/apps/chat/src

for "Group calling", you must create a channel first

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30944902)